# DPM (data protection manager) backup with SQL Server 2014 AlwaysOn

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-backups, alwayson, dpm

I have a SQL Server 2014 AlwaysOn cluster. I created a protection group on DPM, first backup is successfull but when DPM tries to get incremental(tlog for every 15') backup of databases which are member of a availability group, it fails. Other databases (system databases) which are not in availability group succeed. You can find error detail and a screenshot below.

DPM and Sql Server 2014 Versions :

DPM : Service Pack 1 4.1.34170.0
Sql Server 2014 : 12.04100.1

The error :

> The replica of DATABASENAME on machine.domain.com is inconsistent with the protected data source. All protection activities for data source will fail until the replica is synchronized with consistency check. (ID: 3106)
>   DPM failed the current backup because the previously standalone SQL database is now a part of a SQL Availability Group.
>   Database: DATABASENAME (ID: 32030).

Screenshot :

[DPM Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8qjx.png) and
[DPM Create New Protection Group Selection Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhuYg.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hope this helps: We have Sql Server 2014 AlwaysOn cluster and backups with DPM are going fine. We take full backups each night and tlog backups every 15'. Never tried incremental backups with DPM, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sorry for misunderstanding, with incremental backup I mean tlog for every 15'.I edit the post.

Comment: consistency Check won't work? Also, Is the secondary node active? Are you taking backups from that secondary?

Comment: Secondary node is active and readable, we tried all the options Prefer Secondary, secondary only, primary and any replica.I think we do something wrong at the beginning when we create protection group wizard when selecting group member.Because there is no cluster specific option or any selectable database under cluster member, we can only select or see databases under primary or secondary members.

Comment: verceli I added a screenshot as the name "DPM Create New Protection Group Selection Screenshot" and you can check.

Comment: We have 3 protection groups. One on each server with Databases that are not on AlwaysOn AGs and one exclusively with DBs related with AlwaysOn

Comment: Vercelli would you please be more clear, I have difficulty in understanding.

Comment: We don't have all our databases in the instance on Availability Groups. In DPM we created a Protection Group Exclusively for the DBs that are on AlwaysOn Availability Groups.We created another Protection Group for the DBs that are not on AlwaysOn Availability Groups. Hope it helps.